# Whats wrong about my code?? please help me

Tags: java

BlueJ keeps writing I have an error in the line

```
int[] row = arr[i];
```

and I don't have any other idea how to put the array in the i row of arr into the array row.
the problem is in the method `specialAll()`.

```
public static boolean isIn(int num, int dig) {
    int is;
    boolean bool = false;
    while (num != 0) {
        is = num % 10;
        if (is == dig) {
            bool = true;
        }
        num = num / 10;
    }
    return bool;
}

public static boolean specialArr(int[] arr) {
    int i, dig, num;
    boolean bool = true;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        num = arr[i + 1];
        dig = (arr[i]) % 10;
        if (!isIn(num, dig)) {
            bool = false;
        }
    }
    return bool;
}

public static boolean specialAll(int[][] arr) {
    int i;
    boolean bool = true;
    for (i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++) {
        int[] row = arr[i];
        if (!specialArr(row)) {
            bool = false;
        }
    }
    return bool;
}
```

when I run the method and input as arr the matrix

```
{ { 12, 525, 53, 8367, 17, 471 }, { 12, 525, 53, 8365, 152, 22 } }
```

which is supposed to return true, the program stops in the middle and writes:

> `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 at Excersise10.specialAll(Excersise10.java:42)

Comment: are you sure that the error is in this line not the next? I don't see any problems int this code but if you don't have overloaded version of `specialAll` method it will definitely raise an error

Comment: I think there is an error in specialArr(row) line and you just show the code of function specialArr()

Comment: when I run the method and input as arr the matrix {{12,525,53,8367, 17, 471},{12,525,53,8365,152,22}}, which is supposed to return true, the program stops in the middle and writes: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at Excersise10.specialAll(Excersise10.java:42)

Comment: I would like to reproduce the problem but I can't. I don't know what `specialArr()` is.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: sure, Ill add it

Comment: The error is because you are taking on your matrix you have only 2 rows so when you are asking arr[i] then this tries to take the next row since your loop is on length the rows and not columns, so you get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: I'll try, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In your for loop, don't put `arr[0].length`, rather use `arr.length`. Try with this:

```
public static boolean specialAll(int[][] arr) {
    int i;
    boolean bool = true;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int[] row = arr[i];
        if (!specialArr(row)) {
            bool = false;
        }
    }
    return bool;
}
```

The reason is, you are using multi-dimensional array. Your input array, `{ { 12, 525, 53, 8367, 17, 471 }, { 12, 525, 53, 8365, 152, 22 } }` makes the array size like this: `int[2][6]`; So, here `arr.length` is 2 and `arr[0].length` is the second dimension, i.e. 6.

So, now you should understand why you are getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Simply because when you are executing this line `int[] row = arr[i];` at some point you are passing the value of `i` greater than `1` whereas in this case the valid one should be less than 2 `(arr.length)`.

Comment: I will try, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The error is speaking for itself, `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` it clearly means you are using the index which is not in the array. In such case always look where are you using indexing, `for-loop` condition and your increment statement.

What you are using as `for-loop` termination condition is the length of the first element of the multi-dimensional array `arr[][]`, in your case it values are:

> {{12,525,53,8367, 17, 471},{12,525,53,8365,152,22}}

Take look at the first array it's length is **6**, so the `for-loop` will go like:

```
int [] row = arr[0]; // i = 0
int [] row = arr[1]; // i = 1
int [] row = arr[2]; // i = 2, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException
```

**Solution:** Instead of using `i < arr[0].length` you should use `i < arr.legnth`,in this way it will never go out of the bound.